# How can I acquire "Arena Token" in War Metal?

Tags: war-metal

I wonder what the ways to get "Arena Token" in War Metal.
On [wm.blem.org](http://wm.blem.org/token.php?tokenId=41) it says "Aquired from Arena"
I never got one from Arena fights yet.
Are there any specific things needed to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [War-Metal Wiki](http://warmetal.wikia.com/wiki/Arena)

> Arena Rank and Arena Tokens
>
> Awarded at the end of daily session
> based on Arena Rank. The higher the
> Arena Rank number the closer the
> player is to the top of the Arena Rank
> leaderboard for that day. More Arena
> Tokens are awarded for being higher on
> the leaderboard. Unclaimed rewards for
> participation in the Arena are
> received when the player clicks
> "Collect Reward" after the duration of
> that Arena has been concluded. Up to
> six (6) [Arena Tokens](http://warmetal.wikia.com/wiki/Arena_Token) may be earned per
> day.

Comment: ah there is a wiki :D